# Elastic collisions between cubes and walls

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple scene with two cubes and walls as shown bellow.

The right ball starts moving with initial instant force along the x-axis and collides with the first ball and reflect off a vertical wall. Each collision in the system is supposed to be absolutely elastic.

***I just want to add some initial force to the right ball*** and everything else will happen by itself

```c#
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-1,0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

I also add *Rigidbody2D* and *Physics material* on walls and cubes with **Friction 0**, **Bounciness 1** and **Gravity Scale 0**.

But there is no bounce in the scene

[image]

Comment: What happens instead of the bounce then, can you please describe? It just gets stuck on the wall?

Comment: Have you set materials to bounce?

Comment: Checkout the duplicate link, this should answer your question.